How to update parameter in API URL when clicking "next" button
I am building a website based on the Jikan API. I am able to fetch the data I need. However, as there are 1000s of entries, they are behind pagination, which I can access this info fine.
What I want to be able to accomplish is to update the API parameter based on the click of a button to cycle through pages.
I have been able to add the functionality for the button and it works as intended, however, the API URL does not update, so I only ever have access to the first page of results.
My server component to fetch the API is below:
import NextPage from './../components/PaginationButtons';

export default async function AnimeList() {
    let current_page = 1
    let data = await fetch(`https://api.jikan.moe/v4/anime?page=${current_page}`)
    let anime = await data.json()

    const total_pages = anime.pagination.last_visible_page
    const page = anime.pagination.current_page



    return (
        <div>
             
            <div className="flex flex-col flex-wrap">
                <ul>
                    {anime.data.map(a => (
                        <li>{a.title}</li>
                    ))}
                </ul>
            </div>
            
            <NextPage
                current_page={current_page}
                total_pages={total_pages}
                page={page}
            />  
        </div>
    )
}

My client component for the button is below:
"use client"

export default function NextPage({ current_page, total_pages }) {
    
    return (
        <>
            <div className="join">
                <button className="join-item btn" onClick={() => current_page--}>Previous Page</button>
                <p>{current_page} <span>of</span> {total_pages}</p>
                <button className="join-item btn" onClick={() => current_page++}>Next Page</button>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}


The API URL never updates because the value of current_page never changes. You are trying to change it with the onClick handler functions in the NextPage component, but you should never directly modify a prop passed to a React component within that component. The React way to do what you want is with the useState hook and passing a function to NextPage that will update the value in the parent component AnimeList. Here is how you can do it:
Change the AnimeList component file to:
"use client"

import NextPage from './../components/PaginationButtons';
import { useState } from 'react';

export default function AnimeList() {
  const [current_page, set_current_page] = useState(1)
  const [anime, setAnime] = useState(null)

  const getAnime = async () => {
    let response = await fetch(`https://api.jikan.moe/v4/anime?page=${current_page}`)
    setAnime(await response.json())
  }
  getAnime()

  if (!anime) return false

  const total_pages = anime.pagination.last_visible_page
  const page = anime.pagination.current_page

  return (
    <div>
      {/* ... */}
      <NextPage
        current_page={current_page}
        total_pages={total_pages}
        page={page}
        set_current_page={set_current_page}
      /> 
    </div>
  )
}

Change the NextPage component file to:
"use client"

export default function NextPage({
  current_page,
  total_pages,
  set_current_page,
}) {    
    return (
        <>
            <div className="join">
                <button
                  className="join-item btn"
                  onClick={() => set_current_page((current_page - 1) || 1)}
                >
                  Previous Page
                </button>
                <p>{current_page} <span>of</span> {total_pages}</p>
                <button
                  className="join-item btn"
                  onClick={() => set_current_page(current_page + 1)}
                >
                  Next Page
                </button>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}

Note that you must now include the "use client" directive in the AnimeList component file. If AnimeList is server-side rendered it will not be able to pass the set_current_page function to the NextPage client component, because the function cannot be serialized.

Thank you for this. I implemented this, but ran in to an issue where async and await cannot be used in "use client", so I added a useEffect to resolve this.
So the above worked, but tweaked it to add this:
useEffect(() => {
const fetchAnimes = async () => {
try {
const response = await fetch(https://api.jikan.moe/v4/anime?page=${current_page})
const data = await response.json()
setAnime(data)
} finally {
setLoading(false)
}
}
fetchAnimes()

},[current_page])

@S.Lowe Thank you for pointing out that oversight. I edited my answer to show how it can be done without useEffect, which is somewhat simpler and what the NextJS Docs suggest. While you cannot make a NextJS client component an async function you can use async functions within the component, so you can define one and immediately call it.
